# what is stable version of ejabberd xmpp server?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

what is stable version of ejabberd  xmpp server? 
Please answer this simple questions. As I have setup 16.08 successfully. 
But one of network administrator keep saying that it is not stable version. 
Please put some light on this question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. It's recommended that always go for latest version of ejabberd. Because of many latest features and bug fixes with latest release.